# How to Segue from View Controller to TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want to show the Chat with the selected User, if the current user selected any Conversation in `ConversationViewcontroller`.

This time, my solution looks like that, but it doesn't work:

Notification setup in `ConversationViewController` I call it in customization and call it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
     func customization()  {
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
//         notification setup
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pushToUserMesssages(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showUserMessages"), object: nil)
}
```

Show ChatViewController with given user:

```
@objc func pushToUserMesssages(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let user = notification.userInfo?["user"] as? UserModel {
        self.selectedUser = user
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Preparing the segue in `ConversationViewController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
        vc.currentUser = self.selectedUser
    }
}
```

Performing Segue in TableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if self.items.count > 0 {
        self.selectedUser = self.items[indexPath.row].user
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

But if I tap to the Chat I want to open, nothing works. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: where you post the notification , show complete context

Comment: edited the question. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showUserMessages"), object: nil, userInfo: ["user":user])
```

where-ever you need to make the transition

Comment: Thank you. Where to insert this codeline? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: it will do the same job as segue ? does segue works ??

Comment: No segue doesn't work. I put inside a segue in storyboard between both viewControllers and call it "segue". Should normally work.

Comment: connect the segue to the yellow top icon of the vc , also set table delegete , and sure when you click didSelect that `if self.items.count > 0`